# Selection.InsertFile C# Error

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-addins

I am working on Office add-in. I am stuck into a problem. I want to add word document as linked object into another word document using c# and VSTO. I dig into and found that for this purpose I have to use **"INCLUDETEXT"** field. In VSTO InsertFile fuction has a parameter named **"Link"**, if this parameter is set to **true** then the specified word document is inserted as linked object.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace WordAddIn1
{
    public partial class MyRibbon
    {
        string txt = "";
        bool hhh = false;
        string file_name = "";
        string file_path = "";
        DataObject o;
        string cmp="";

        private void MyRibbon_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {
            checkBox1.Checked = false;
            o = (DataObject)Clipboard.GetDataObject();

        }

        private void checkBox1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {

            if (checkBox1.Checked == true && (o.ContainsText()||o.ContainsImage()))
            {


                txt = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Text.Trim();
                file_name = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Name;
                file_path = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Path;
                cmp = file_path + "\\" + file_name;
                hhh = txt.Length > 0;

                if (hhh)
                {

                    Console.Beep();

                }
            }

            else
            {

                if (o.ContainsText() || o.ContainsImage())
                {
                    string FileName = "C:\\final.docx";
                    object range = "hashim";

                     object ConfirmConversions = false;
                     object Link = true;
                     object Attachment = false;


                     Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.InsertFile(FileName, range,ConfirmConversions ,Link,  Attachment);

                     Form1 frm = new Form1(file_name.ToString(),file_path.ToString());
                    frm.Show();

                }

            }

    }



    }
}
```

The line

**Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.InsertFile(FileName, range,ConfirmConversions ,Link,  Attachment);**

does not show any error in editor or during compilation but when I use my add-in in office it gives error on this line and said **"Command Failed"**

Here is error screenshot

[image]

Here is StackTrace of Error

[image]

But When I simply use this line it gives no error and file is inserted but not as a linked object.

**Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.InsertFile(FileName)**

Where is the problem ? Also tell me if you have better idea to insert linked object (Word document) into other document. ?

Comment: Does the document to be inserted contain a bookmark named "hashim"?

Comment: @DirkVollmar yes it contains

Comment: Are you able to successfully insert the INCLUDETEXT field manually? On the *Insert* tab choose *Quick Parts* > *Fields...*, then select INCLUDETEXT on the left and click on the *Field Codes* button. Then enter `INCLUDETEXT "C:\\final.docx" hashim` as the field code. If there is a problem with the file or the bookmark name, you likely will get a better error message than the one from the COMException.

Comment: @DirkVollmar thank you for your comment. I got it working. Thanks alot sir. Thanks alot.

Comment: Can you tell what your solution was? Then your post can also be helpful for others :-)

Comment: @DirkVollmar yes I provide solution so that other may be get benefit from this.

Comment: @DirkVollmar please go thorugh my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** There is no error in the above code. Problem lies that I do not have a bookmark object in my word file that is going to be linked. I have created one with the name **"hashim"** and it works like a charm.

**Solution:**

If we go to the documentation of **InsertFile**

```
Summary:
        //     Inserts all or part of the specified file.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   FileName:
        //     Required String. The path and file name of the file to be inserted. If you don't
        //     specify a path, Microsoft Word assumes the file is in the current folder.
        //
        //   Range:
        //     Optional Object. If the specified file is a Word document, this parameter refers
        //     to a bookmark. If the file is another type (for example, a Microsoft Excel worksheet),
        //     this parameter refers to a named range or a cell range (for example, R1C1:R3C4).
        //
        //   ConfirmConversions:
        //     Optional Object. True to have Word prompt you to confirm conversion when inserting
        //     files in formats other than the Word Document format.
        //
        //   Link:
        //     Optional Object. True to insert the file by using an INCLUDETEXT field.
        //
        //   Attachment:
        //     Optional Object. True to insert the file as an attachment to an e-mail message.
```

See the parameter **Range** If the file we are linking is a **"Word Document"** then there should be a bookmark created in that file with a name. You must pass this bookmark name in Range object. Like

```
object Range = "hashim";
```

here **hashim** is a bookmark name in the file that is linked into other document file.

If the bookmark is not specified then it must give error.

Now if the linking object is an **Excel Document** then the range object must contains the cells information like

```
object Range = "R1C1:R3C4";
```

Here **"R1C1:R3C4"** is cell range in excel that we want to link in our document.

Note: We can add complete or part of excel or word document. Just see the [Range Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845882.aspx) documentation.

Hope answer is clear to you.
Thank you